# Why do multiple uses to Notification.Builder crash the app?

Tags: java, android, notificationmanager

I am making a project that will display notifications to the user if set `setLuminLevels()` `setHumidLevels()` `setTempLevels()`  return true.

This is my main

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        NotificationCompat.Builder lumin =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.index)
                        .setContentTitle("Greenhouse Warning:")
                        .setContentText("Luminosity Out of range!");

        NotificationCompat.Builder humid =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.index)
                        .setContentTitle("Greenhouse Warning:")
                        .setContentText("Humidity Out of range!");

        NotificationCompat.Builder temp =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.index)
                        .setContentTitle("Greenhouse Warning:")
                        .setContentText("Temperature Out of range!");

        int mNotificationId1 = 001;
        int mNotificationId2 = 002;
        int mNotificationId3 = 003;

        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr1 = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr2 = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr3 = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        //set and check the displayed levels
        if(setLuminLevels()) mNotifyMgr1.notify(mNotificationId1, lumin.build());
        if(setHumidLevels()) mNotifyMgr2.notify(mNotificationId2, humid.build());
        if(setTempLevels() ) mNotifyMgr3.notify(mNotificationId3, temp.build() );
    }
```

Why would this code crash my app? How do I use mutliple notifications?

Crash report:

```
                                                    --------- beginning of crash
07-20 14:23:57.136 2645-2645/com.joanjantz_lee.greenhouse E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.joanjantz_lee.greenhouse, PID: 2645
                                                                            java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "26.57"
                                                                                at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:521)
                                                                                at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
                                                                                at com.joanjantz_lee.greenhouse.MainActivity$3.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:206)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbmz.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbnz.zzYj(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzboc$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Do you have any log about that crash? By the way, I belive that mNotifyMgr1, mNotifyMgr2, mNotifyMgr3 is the same instance so you dont need that many variables.

Comment: @user1779222 I don't have one no, I'll keep you notified when I do though

Comment: @user1779222 it's what I thought, but how would I generate notifications as new instances? I thought that **new** took care of such things

Comment: Can you post that log?

Comment: @user1779222 see above, just added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider these lines from your log:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "26.57"
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:521)                                                                                
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)                                                                                
at com.joanjantz_lee.greenhouse.MainActivity$3.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:206)
```

You have a listener for the onDataChange event which is being called, and is attempting to parse a string into an integer.  The string contains "26.57" which is not a valid integer.

Look at line 206 of your MainActivity.java

PS: user1779222 is right. The NotificationManager is a singleton so you only need one reference to it.